# FindGeneratingFunction gives up too easily

Tags: series-expansion, sequence, integer-sequence, discrete

I am trying to automatically find a generating function from the coefficients of a simple rational function using Mathematica's [FindGeneratingFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeneratingFunction.html):

```
f[x_] := (x + 2 x^2 + x^3 + 2 x^4 + x^5)/(1 - 2 x + 2 x^3 - x^4)
coefs = Table[SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}], {n, 0, 4}]
FindGeneratingFunction[coefs, x, FunctionSpace -> "Rational", TimeConstraint -> 999999]
```

However, even after specifying the right `FunctionSpace` and increasing the `TimeConstraint`, Mathematica *immediately* gives up on finding a solution. Does anyone know how I can make Mathematica search harder for a solution?

Also, if I restrict the list to the first 4 elements, it does find a generating function, but *only* if I *remove* both the `FunctionSpace` and `TimeConstraint` parameters. Why?

Comment: You need at least 12 series coefficient, a[0] to a[11], in order to uniquely determine the rational generating function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_] := (x + 2 x^2 + x^3 + 2 x^4 + x^5)/(1 - 2 x + 2 x^3 - x^4)

coefs = Table[SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}], {n, 0, 11}];
```

The option [`FunctionSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionSpace.html) should be specified as "RationalFunction" rather than "Rational". And as pointed out in the comment by Samos, you need more coefficients.

```
g[x_] = FindGeneratingFunction[coefs, x, 
   FunctionSpace -> "RationalFunction"] // Simplify

(* -((x (1 + 2 x + x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4))/((-1 + x)^3 (1 + x))) *)
```

Verifying equivalence,

```
f[x] == g[x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Or use the default for `FunctionSpace`

```
FindGeneratingFunction[coefs, x] == f[x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```